# ASP.NET MVC3, Collection inside Model using Forms GET method and is URL/SEO friendly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, url-rewriting, icollection

Let me describe the code I have and then I ask the question.

I have such class

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public virtual ICollection<SomeObject> fweek { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SomeObject> ftxt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SomeObject> fbool { get; set; }
}
```

Then I'm creating editor for such model:

```cs
@model MyModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", FormMethod.GET))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.fweek)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ftxt)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.fbool)
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

If I submit my form as a result I'm redirected to similar URL:

```
http://localhost:3517/pl-PL/Places/Search?
fbool%5B0%5D.Value=false&
fweek%5B0%5D.Value=1&
fweek%5B1%5D.Value=2&
ftxt%5B0%5D.Value=23fasf&
ftxt%5B1%5D.Value=assffg&
```

The question is:
Is it possible to rewrite such URL (especially %5B and %5D sequences) to become more SEO/User friendly?
Lets say this example URL may look like this:

```
http://localhost:3517/pl-PL/Places/Search?
fbool.Value=false&
fweek.Value=1&
fweek.Value=2&
ftxt.Value=23fasf&
ftxt.Value=assffg&
```

Thank you for any help.
Regards.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce that scenario.  I cut/pasted your code, adding a class SomeObject with single property 'Value' as string, deduced from your example URL.  

Html.EditorFor produced no HTML, nor did I get redirected to any URL, so how did you arrive at this?

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:3517/pl-PL/Places/Search?
fbool.Value=false&
fweek.Value=1&
fweek.Value=2&
ftxt.Value=23fasf&
ftxt.Value=assffg&
```

This would not work in any scenario because you're sending multiple form fields with the same name, so they need to have an index associated with them. I.E.

```
fweek[0].Value=1&fweek[1].Value =2
```

Without the index how can you determine which `fweek` is which?

Why not just post this form?

Comment: Determining which `fweek` is which is unimportant cause this is an unordered collection of some values... I need to shorten and beautify this URL. So maybe there is any way to do this (maybe to omit `.Value` suffix without changing the `fweek` object declaration)?